# Parse Twitter Login - Choose Which Twitter Account

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that lets users login with their twitter account. It uses the [Parse](https://parse.com/) API to do this. Following is the code that handles the login:

```
- (IBAction)twitterAuthButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *appUser, NSError *error) {
        if (!appUser) return;
        //todo: display loading indicator
        [[CPUserCacheProvider _] loginWithSuccess:^{
            [self showHideAuthButtons];
            [self updateNameAndAvatar];
        } andFailure:^{
            UIAlertView *failWhale = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter Login Failed!" message:@"There was a problem with logging in with Twitter." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [failWhale show];
        }];

        NSLog(@"CPSettingsViewController.twitterAuthButtonPressed: Twitter User Logged in %@", appUser.username);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:userAuthChangedNotification object:nil];
    }];

}
```

I have a personal Twitter account and one I use for testing. The first time I logged in, I logged in with my personal account. I would like to log in with my test account. But every time I login, the app automatically logs me in with my personal account. I have even deleted the corresponding PFUser (trough Parse's dashboard) and the app still automatically logs me in with my personal account.

How I can make the app make me ask for my Twitter credentials again? I wonder if there is something I can do in iOS settings to make the app forget my personal Twitter account.

Comment: Did you try changing the twitter account from the settings app? That should work if I am understanding your problem correctly. First I would just go into the settings app and replace your old account with the new test account.Then I would delete the app from your device, and run it again with the updated twitter settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[PFUser logout]` this is the way to log a user out. The user is cached locally when you call to login and so you'll need to destroy that by logging out.